# Can we create two or many strings.xml file in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create two or more strings.xml files in my android program. I can create a .xml file with different name but how i can link second xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can name it whatever you want. Just put all of them into `res/values`. What matters is the location and the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many as you want, `strings` is just the name, which will be used as the ID, but nothing prevents you creating as many files as you want (you'll have to respect the structure, though).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can name your xml files however you like. They must be in the `res/values` folder and they will be accessible through the `R` static class which contains all the resources. The `R` class is dynamically generated when you build your app.

So, if your file name is foo.xml, you can access it in code through `R.foo.value1`